# Unable to load directive dynamically in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dynamic-programming

I have lots of condition on which I have to change my view dynamically so I need some way in which I just change in my object and view will react to it.

I am trying to load directive dynamically using a variable as follow:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="type in testDirectiveJson" ng-click="setDirective(type)">{{type}}</button> {{newDirective}}
    <load-directive type="newDirective"></load-directive>
    <script src="./test.directive.js"></script>
</body>
```

here is my js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.testDirectiveJson = {
         first: '1-directive',
         sec: '2-directive',
         third: '3-directive',
     }
     $scope.lastName = "Doe";
     $scope.newDirective = ""
     $scope.setDirective = function(type) {
         console.log(type);
         $scope.newDirective = type;
         $scope.$apply();
     }
 }).directive("loadDirective", function($compile) {
     return {
         scope: {
             Dtype: '=type'
         },
         link: function(scope, element) {
             var generatedTemplate = '<div ' + scope.Dtype +
                 ' ></div>';
             element.append($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
         },
         restrict: 'E'
     };
 }).directive("1Directive", function() {

     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive A!</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("2Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! B</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("3Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! C</h1>"
     };
 });
```

its not working as expected.

it's work fine if I pass directive directly.

Comment: "its not working as expected" : can you explain?

Comment: did you try $watch for newDirective variable? I think you should detect the newDirective value is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `$watch` for the isolated scope `Dtype` to append the html.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.$watch('Dtype', function(newVal) {
                var generatedTemplate = '<div ' + scope.Dtype +
                    ' ></div>';
                  element.html($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));

             });
         }
```

Also, you should need to remove `$scope.$apply()` from the `$scope.setDirective` method otherwise it will throw the error `$apply already in progress`.

**Working snippet**:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.testDirectiveJson = {
         first: '1-directive',
         sec: '2-directive',
         third: '3-directive',
     }
     $scope.lastName = "Doe";
     $scope.newDirective = ""
     $scope.setDirective = function(type) {
         console.log(type);
         $scope.newDirective = type;
     }
 }).directive("loadDirective", function($compile, $timeout) {
     return {
         scope: {
             Dtype: '=type'
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.$watch('Dtype', function(newVal) {
                var generatedTemplate = '<div ' + scope.Dtype +
                    ' ></div>';
                  element.html($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
               
             });
         },
         restrict: 'E'
     };
 }).directive("1Directive", function() {

     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive A!</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("2Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! B</h1>"
     };
 }).directive("3Directive", function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         template: "<h1>Made by a directive! C</h1>"
     };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="type in testDirectiveJson" ng-click="setDirective(type)">{{type}}</button> {{newDirective}}
    <load-directive type="newDirective"></load-directive>
    <!--<script src="./test.directive.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

Comment: Hey its working fine but it keep adding multiple times

Comment: You can use `element.html` instead of `element.append` above

Comment: thats what I answered in my answer @Rhushikesh

Comment: element.empty().append($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));

Comment: yeah that's also will work. I updated `element.html` which looks good. You should add jQuery as reference since JQLite with angular don't have `html`. You can check the above sample now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use html instead of append if you want that element to be replaced and inside directive watch for the change because each change click will need the directive to re-compile like this

```
 scope.$watch('Dtype', function() {
    var generatedTemplate = '<div ' + scope.Dtype +  ' ></div>';      
    element.html($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
 });
```

See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J4ccY/106/)

Answer (score 0):

Link is too late in the directive loading process to dynamically modify the DOM. You need to make your changes during the pre-compile stage.

See the Angular docs on directive compilation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile